# changing encoding UTF8 to UTF8 BOM with rebol

Tags: utf-8, rebol, byte-order-mark, rebol3

I have a file which is encoded as UTF-8.  I'd like to change it to UTF-8 + [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

This is what I wrote, but it didn't work:

```
write/binary %mycontacts.csv insert read/binary %mycontacts.csv #{EFBBBF}
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing a pipeline of processing, the return result of INSERT is the series position you passed in:

```
>> str: "ution"

>> print insert str {Rebol}
ution
```

Note that if you use an intermediate variable (as above) then that variable will point to the beginning of your newly inserted content after the operation:

```
>> print str
Rebolution
```

If you don't want to use an intermediate variable, but want to get the beginning of your inserted content, you'll need to skip backwards the length of the content you inserted:

```
>> print skip insert str {Rebol} -5
Rebolution
```

But if you know you inserted at the head of the series then you can just use HEAD:

```
>> print head insert str {Rebol}
Rebolution
```

So because you're inserting at the head of the series for your byte-order marker, the following should work for your case:

```
write/binary %mycontacts.csv head insert read/binary %mycontacts.csv #{EFBBBF}
```